# Remove sidebar of a module

Tags: layout

I've install a group deal module. The group deal products will display in group deal layout while the normal product will use my theme layout. The sidebar is expected ***only will be displayed in group deal layout*** but it should not be displayed in my default product layout.

The group deal layout xml is containing a row which will display a sidedeals.phtml, see:

app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\groupdeals.xml (product_view section)

```
<block type="groupdeals/product_list_sidedeals" name="groupdeals.sidedeals" template="groupdeals/product/list/sidedeals.phtml" before="-"/>
```

and my theme layout xml file is in:

app\design\frontend\default\metroshop\layout\catalog.xml

the product which is not a group deal will use this layout.

But now, the default product view is display the sidedeals.phtml, it should not be displayed.

How can i fix the product?

Answer (score 2):

In your catalog.xml's product_view section, write below lines of code. that will remove block from left

```
<reference name="left">
            <remove name="groupdeals.sidedeals">
</reference>
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: i've already tried this before asking the question, now i use this line of code 
<?php if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == "groupdeals"): ?> in sidedeals.phtml
to display the content hardcodely

Comment: Is the sidebar on the left? Otherwise if it is on the right, use `<reference name="right">`.

Comment: right, i use right.

Comment: it's not work....